# Minting firebaseId tokens is unusually slow

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

For authenticated API calls I'm generating a firebaseId token each time, as in the code below. But this sometimes takes up to 2-3 seconds to mint the token, which adds up to a slow UX. Are there any workarounds to this, perhaps to store the token for a longer period or even indefinitely? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

```
async fetchFromAPIAuthenticatedTimeout(url, params) {
    this.fetchStampA = (new Date()).getTime()
    try {
        const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
        this.fetchStampB = (new Date()).getTime()
        const response = await fetch(url,params)
        if (response.status != 200) {
            throw Error("api-error");
        }
        var json = null;
        try {
            json = await response.json();
        } catch (error) {
            throw Error("api-error")
        }
        this.fetchStampD = (new Date()).getTime()
        console.log(">> token",this.fetchStampB-this.fetchStampA)
        console.log(">> fetch",this.fetchStampC-this.fetchStampB)
        return json.result
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        throw Error(error.message)
    }
}

// Prints:
// >> token 2198
// >> fetch 319
```

Comment: You are forcing a token refresh by passing `true` into `getIdToken()`. It would likely be considerably faster if you weren't forcing a round trip to the server and used the local token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [reference doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#getidtoken), getIdToken() will automatically refresh the token if it has expired. So there's no need to force a refresh on each call. Removing this will prevent the round trip and speed up the requests considerably, and also keep you out of quota trouble--which you will run into as your app scales.

**UPDATE: This edge case is fixed. Tokens now refresh a short time before they expire. So there's never a need to use the force refresh for this use case.** Note that there may still be an edge case where, if you send the request seconds before expiration and there is latency, that the server may not call verifyIdToken() before the expiration occurs. So you may want to implement retry logic or check the expiration time (see [IdTokenResult#expirationTime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.IDTokenResult.html#expirationtime)) and force a refresh if it's extremely close to the timestamp. But certainly not on each request.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, although may I ask why the boolean is there in the first place if it already contains the logic to refresh itself if necessary? I think I was confused because the example in the docs has the flag set to true: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: There are a couple sophisticated use cases where this is useful, and it was originally added to deal with the edge case I described here. Note that it's no longer necessary, as that edge case was removed in a recent enhancement.